# How can I use getStaticPaths with an authenticated external API in Next.js and Auth0?

Tags: next.js, auth0, getstaticpaths

I'm trying to use getStaticPaths to generate dynamic page routes in my Next.js application. However, in order to call my external API, I need to pass a Bearer token for authentication purposes. I'm using Auth0 for authentication and was wondering how to achieve this in my getStaticPaths function?

Here's my current code for getStaticPaths:

```
export async function getStaticPaths() {
  const res = await fetch('https://myapi.com/projects')
  const projects = await res.json()

  const paths = projects.map((project) => ({
    params: { id: project.id },
  }))

  return { paths, fallback: false }
}
```

I need to add the Bearer token to the request headers in order to successfully authenticate with my external API. How can I achieve this using the Auth0 Next.js library?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

```
 const Token = await //here call your api and get the token 
 const res = await fetch('https://myapi.com/projects', {
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${Token}`,
    },
  });
```

you can make an async function to get your token from the api

```
async function getToken () {
     //call you api here 

     return Token

}
```

and now you can say

```
const Token  = await getToken()
```